# Проблема ссылка на метод против лямбда метода или почему NPE без вызова метода

Tags: java, optional

Всем привет. Сегодня обнаружил занятную штуку касательно работы ссылки на метод.

Есть класс

```
public class A {
   private String b;

   public final String getB() {
       return b;
   }

   public final String setB(String b) {
       this.b = b;
       return b;
   }
}
```

Есть какой-то код, который вызывает **Optional**

```
A a = c.getA();
Optional.ofNullable(value).map(a::setB)
```

где `c.getA() == null`

В таком случает получим NPE, даже если value будет **null**.

Но если заменим ссылку на метод на лямбда выражение NPE пропадет

```
A a = c.getA();
Optional.ofNullable(value).map(v -> a.setB(v))
```

Прошу объяснить в какой момент извлекается ссылка на метод и почему это происходит до вызова метода **map()**?

**UPD:** добавил рабочий пример

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String value = null;
        Container container = new Container(null);
        A aValue = container.getaValue();

        Optional.ofNullable(value).ifPresent(v -> aValue.setB(v)); // Отработает Ок
        Optional.ofNullable(value).ifPresent(aValue::setB); // NPE
    }

    public static class A {
        private String b;

        public final String getB() {
            return b;
        }

        public final void setB(String b) {
            this.b = b;
        }
    }

    public static class Container {
        private A aValue;

        public Container(A aValue) {
            this.aValue = aValue;
        }

        public final A getaValue() {
            return aValue;
        }
    }
```

Comment: @NowhereMan Добавил

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`map(a::setB)` действительно отличается от `map(v -> a.setB(v))`

Дело в том, что синтаксис `a::setB` является ссылкой на метод `setB` переменной `a`, лямбда сама по себе является функцией `v -> a.setB(v)`

```
var lam = v -> a.setB(v)
var ref = a::setB // a -> является ссылкой на объект определённого класса, если a = null, то получается null::setB

System.out.println(lam("1"));
System.out.println(ref("2"));
```

ссылка на функцию вычисляется в момент прохода по методу (во время интерпретации байт кода), т.е. в момент присваивания ссылки на функцию в методе `map(a::setB)`. В то время как у `v -> a.setB(v)` вызов `a` будет вызван только тогда, когда будет вызвано тело метода `map`, но так как есть проверка на `null`, само тело `map` не будет вызвано.